# Como creo una clase log en c++?

Tags: c++, c, archivo, txt, logger

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con **sockets** (**servidor y cliente**) pero no se como hacer una clase de **`logger`** que vaya escribiendo en un **.txt** todas las cosas que esta haciendo el servidor; es decir que vaya dejando un rastro de todas las operaciones de la `BBDD`, cuando se abre el socket, tc... junto con la hora y día del sistema. Alguien me podría echar un cable con la clase (.cpp & .h)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include "BaseDeDatos.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "Hotel.h"
#define SERVER_IP "127.0.0.1"
#define SERVER_PORT 9000
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

BaseDeDatos bd("JIE_BOOKING.db");
int switch1, switch2, switch3, num, d;
char a[20], b[20], c[20], e[20];
int r;

WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET conn_socket; //el que lleva la conexion
SOCKET comm_socket; //el que lo comunica
struct sockaddr_in server;
struct sockaddr_in client;
char sendBuff[512], recvBuff[512]; // lo que yo envio, lo que yo recibo
int opcionA,opcionC;
Hotel h;
bd.abrirBD();
printf("\nInitialising Winsock...\n"); // inicializa la libreria
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
    printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    return -1;
}

printf("Initialised.\n");

//SOCKET creation creacion del socket( la primera estructura
if ((conn_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

printf("Socket created.\n");
// cual es la ip y cual es el puerto
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_IP); //INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

//BIND (the IP/port with socket)
if (bind(conn_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server,
        sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("Bind failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(conn_socket);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

printf("Bind done.\n"); //DEJAR EL SOCKET EN ESPERA

//LISTEN to incoming connections (socket server moves to listening mode)
if (listen(conn_socket, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("Listen failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(conn_socket);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

//ACCEPT incoming connections (server keeps waiting for them)
printf("Waiting for incoming connections...\n");
int stsize = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
comm_socket = accept(conn_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &stsize);
// Using comm_socket is able to send/receive data to/from connected client
if (comm_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(conn_socket);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}
printf("Incomming connection from: %s (%d)\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr),
        ntohs(client.sin_port));

// Closing the listening sockets (is not going to be used anymore)
closesocket(conn_socket);

//SERVER PROGRAM
do{
    char dn[15], contrasenia[15];
    recv(comm_socket, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff), 0);
    sscanf(recvBuff, "%i", &switch1);
    switch(switch1){
    case 1:

        recv(comm_socket, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff), 0); //Recibe el dn
        sprintf(dn, "%s", recvBuff); //GUARDA EN dn

        recv(comm_socket, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff), 0); //Recibe la contrasenia
        sprintf(contrasenia, "%s", recvBuff); //GUARDA EN contrasenia
        if (strcmp(dn, "ADMIN") == 0 && strcmp(contrasenia, "ADMIN") == 0) { // ENTRA AL ADMINISTRADOR (MENU ADMINISTRADOR)
            r=1;
            sprintf(sendBuff, "%i", r);
                        send(comm_socket, sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), 0);

            cout << "-------PRUEBA-----" << endl;
            do{
                recv(comm_socket, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff), 0); //Recibe la contrasenia
                sscanf(recvBuff,"%d",&opcionA);
                switch(opcionA){
                case 1:
                    recv(comm_socket, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff), 0); //Recibe la contrasenia
                    sscanf(recvBuff,"%s %s %d %s %s %f",h.codH,h.nomH,&h.numHabitaciones,h.dirH,h.locH,&h.precioNoche);
                    bd.insertarHotel(h.codH, h.nomH, h.numHabitaciones, h.locH, h.dirH, h.precioNoche); //INTERTA EL HOTEL RECIBIDO
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                }

            }while(opcionA!=0);
```

Este seria el codigo del servidor que accede a la BBDD y queria hacer una clase `logger` que vaya escribiendo en un .txt todo lo que se esta realizando.

Comment: Esta pregunta es quizás demasiado abstracta. ¿Seguro que no eres capaz de preguntar cosas un pelín más concretas? Una clase de log puede tener multitud de requisitos (poder usar diferentes archivos o salidas, gestionar o no diferentes ámbitos, entorno de multihilo, ...) Deberías reconsiderar la pregunta para que apunte a dudas un poco más concretas

Comment: @eferion que tal de esta forma? Es básicamente como en el lenguaje java tenias la oportunidad de utilizar los logger y de esa manera mostrar lo que estaba sucediendo en el programa. Espero que me puedas ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tirando por lo simple, para guardar mensajes en un archivo no necesitas una clase logger, te basta con abrir un archivo en modo escritura:

```
std::ofstream log("log.txt");
log << "Un mensaje para el log";

// ...

log << "Otro mensaje";
```

Encapsular esta lógica en una clase podría tener sentido para centralizar ciertas tareas, como añadir una marca de tiempo, poner el tipo de mensaje (normal, de error, advertencia, crítico, ...), etc.

Realmente la encapsulación no tiene nada del otro mundo:

```
class Logger
{
    std::ofstream stream;

public:

    Logger(std::string const& file)
        : stream{file.c_str()}
    { }

    // Se desactiva el constructor copia    
    Logger(Logger const&) = delete;

    // Se desactiva el operador copia
    Logger & operator=(Logger const&) = delete;

    Logger & operator <<(std::string const& message)
    {
        stream << message;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Los mecanismos de copia se eliminan porque no puedes abrir un archivo en modo escritura desde dos fuentes diferentes

Esta implementación la puedes complicar todo lo que sea necesario, la clave sería mantener el stream que apunta al archivo en la parte privada de la clase.

Comment: Todavía existen el constructor y la asignación de mover.

Comment: @Mateo cuando desactivas el constructor copia de forma explícita, el de movimiento se desactiva automáticamente y al revés. La solución sería usar `=default` para activar los constructores eliminados (o hacer una implementación propia)